# Let $5 \leq k < n$. Then $2k$ divides $n(n - 1)..... (n - k + 1)$. What should I use permutations or polynomials?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Let $5 \leq k <n$. Then $2k$ divides $n(n-1)\cdots(n-k + 1)$. Is it true? Please provide a proof. I am confused about using induction, polynomial properties or permutations to solve this problem.

Comment: This can be done via elementary number theory.  No reason to use permutations *or* polynomials.  Claim: in any sequence of numbers $a,a+1,a+2,\dots,a+k-1$ there is at least one of those numbers which is divisible by $k$.  (*Proof via the pigeonhole principle*).  Corollary: $k$ divides evenly into $(a)(a+1)\cdots(a+k-1)$.  Now... do similarly for $2$ and argue that the factor of $2$ need not originate from the same term that the factor of $k$ did (*here is where we use the fact that $5\leq k$*).

Answer (score 1):

$k!$ divides $n(n - 1)\cdots(n - k + 1)$ because $n \choose k$ is an integer.

Now $2k$ divides $k!=1\cdot 2 \cdots k$ if $k \ge 3$.